# Ruby on Rails form error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am building an app from an online tutorial. It tracks "Movies" and "Rentals." I am trying to set up the part where you create a new rental. When I submit the form, I get this error:

```
ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError in RentalsController#create
```

Here is the full rentals controller:

```
class RentalsController < ApplicationController

def new
    @movie = Movie.find(params[:id])
    @rental = @movie.rentals.build
end

def create 
    @movie = Movie.find(params[:id])
    @rental = @movie.rentals.build(params[:rental])
    if @rental.save 
        redirect_to new_rental_path(:id => @movie.id)
    end
end 
end
```

It seems to take issue with this line in particular:

```
        @rental = @movie.rentals.build(params[:rental])
```

Here is the Rental model:

```
class Rental < ApplicationRecord
has_one :movie
end
```

Here is the controller for Movies:

```
class MoviesController < ApplicationController

def new 
    @movie = Movie.new
    @movies = Movie.all
end

def create 
    @movie = Movie.new(movie_params)
    if @movie.save
        redirect_to new_movie_path
    end 
end

private

def movie_params
    params.require(:movie).permit(:title, :year)
end 
end
```

Here is the Movie model:

```
class Movie < ApplicationRecord
has_many :rentals
end
```

Here are the routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 resources :movies, :rentals
 root 'movies#new'

end
```

Here is the form:

```
<h1><%= @movie.title %></h1>

<%= form_for @rental, :url => {:action => :create, :id => @movie.id } do |r| %>
Borrowed on: <%= r.text_field :borrowed_on %><br />
Returned on: <%= r.text_field :returned_on %><br /> 
<br />
<%= r.button :submit %> 
<% end %> 
<br />
<%= link_to "back", new_movie_path %>
```

I'm not sure what is going on. From what I can tell, I am copying the tutorial exactly. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: This error happens when you try to send a parameter that you have not added to the params method, in this case you are missing the rental_params method entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't using strong params for `rentals`, hence the `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError` error.

---

This should fix the error:

```
class RentalsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @movie = Movie.find(params[:id])
    @rental = @movie.rentals.build
  end

  def create 
    @movie = Movie.find(params[:id])
    @rental = @movie.rentals.build(rental_params)
    if @rental.save 
        redirect_to new_rental_path(:id => @movie.id)
    end
  end

  private

  def rental_params
    params.require(:rental).permit(:borrowed_on, :rented_on)
  end
end
```

Comment: Now I get this error: "When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument." Any thoughts?

Comment: What does `rental_params` look like? Also, post some stracktrace of the error

Comment: def rental_params
     params.require(:rental).permit(:borrowed_on, :rented_on)
    end